# What is the recommended way to develop a spring boot application for deployment on websphere?

Tags: spring-boot, websphere

We have to use websphere for the production environment of a new application that we are building. I want to Use spring boot to get the rest service developed quickly. But it seems like a problem that a spring boot project has an embedded tomcat in it by default when we will deploy in production to websphere. Is there a best practice or recommendation for how we could develop a spring boot project for deployment on websphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot supports the deployment as a JAR file (Default approach that uses an embedded container such as Tomcat) or as WAR file to an application server (such as WebSphere Application Server - WAS).

You can find in the reference manual the procedure to generate such a war file : [Create a deployable war file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)

To deploy on a WAS environment, you can use this [generator](http://liberty-starter.wasdev.developer.ibm.com/start/) to help you in the configuration.